# How to access JSON values using foreach - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am in php/laravel im using foreach to access the values like:

CODE:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user}}
@endforeach
```

Result:

```
{
    "id": 97,
    "user_id": 68,
    "reporting": "25",
    "created_at": "2017-11-28 09:18:57",
    "updated_at": "2017-11-28 09:18:57",
    "reporting_users": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "attendanceId": 1,
            "name": 68,
            "attendanceDate": "2017-12-04 00:00:00",
            "clockIn": "2017-12-04 05:10:00",
            "clockOut": "2017-12-04 05:10:00",
            "workTime": "2017-12-04 05:10:00",
            "reason": "test",
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ],
    "find_user": {
        "id": 68,
        "attendances_id": 1,
        "name": "Ahsan Khyraj",
        "email": "ahsan22@gmail.com",
        "verificationToken": "nhpyzVQr8YjFJbHvokrzjwee2",
        "status": 1,
        "userType": 1,
        "department": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-11-28 09:18:57",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-28 09:18:57"
    }
}
```

Now how can I access the value `attendanceId` and `email` ?

I am able to access the value of reporting

```
{{$user->reporting}}
```

but how can I access the other values which is inside `reporting_users` and `find_user`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down.

`reporting_users` is an array (Note the `[]` square bracket). So you got to loop it.

`find_user` is an object (Note the `{}`), so you just access it via the `->`.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  {{ $user->find_user->name }}
  @foreach($user->reporting_users as $reporting_user)
     {{ $reporting_user->name }}

  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (View: G:\xampp\htdocs\hrmanagement\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

Comment: Can you update which line exactly it is causing the error?